# Delete files older than 7 days from a remote SFTP with Pentaho

Tags: sftp, pentaho-spoon

I'm using Pentado Data Integration 8.2. I've little experience with Pentaho.

I need create a job with Pentaho that deletes files older than 7 days from a remote SFTP.

I searched, but I couldn't find a solution with remote SFTP.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcom Nokin! Did you write some code to delete those files? Could you share it with us?

Comment: Hello @gmauch.
I didn't write any code to delete those files. I'd like delete those files using Pentaho's components, if it's possible, but I don't know how do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Run ssh component to connect to your home directory. In the `settings` tab under the `command`s tab, run the following command.

```
find /path/to/ \
  -type f \
  -mtime +7 \
  -name '*.txt' \
  -execdir rm -- '{}' \;
```

This will delete all the `txt` files older than 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by just using simple file process step.
first use **get file names** it will give you ***lastmodifiedtime*** as column.
after that filter rows  which are 7 days older. and pass those rows to ***processfile***
. choose delete from drop down in ***processfile*** step.
for 7 days interval use **get system info** for current date and calculator for **currentdate-7days**.
i hope u get it.
sequence for this is like.

```
get file names-->get sys info--> calculator -->filter rows -->process files
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I've inspected 'get file names' object and have for search in a local directory, and I need connect to remote FTP and delete files there (if it's possible).

Comment: then you can use **get file with FTP in job** and pass result to above transformation.   https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/71432-Get-file-name-from-quot-Get-a-file-with-FTP-quot/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but Get File obtain a file from FTP, this file pass to transformation where I read the date and filter (with get sys info, calculator, etc.)...
My doubt is when this arrive to 'process file', this step will delete the downloaded copy, not the file from FTP. Really? (I need delete this file from  remote FTP)